# Search not returning some items sometimes

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, cross-site-publishing

Have a cross-site publishing site set up. Mostly working well. We have a few items that are exhibiting strange return results. They are in a document library and have similar titles.

```
Process Number One — Agile
Process Number One — Waterfall
```

If I search on "Process Number One Agile" I only get the first result, if I search on "Process Number One Waterfall" I get the second one.

If I search on "Process Number One" I only get the first result when I would expect both to be returned. At the bottom of the results it says "1 result."

The odd thing is that the refiner/facets along the side show 2 results, so it knows there should be two.

If I query based on my managed properties it shows the same behavior.

```
path:"thepath/List/" AND ListItemID:169 <-- one correct result
path:"thepath/List/" AND ListItemID:168 <-- one correct result
path:"thepath/List/" AND (ListItemID:169 OR ListItemID:168) <-- only one result
```

At first I thought it was because they had an em dash in the title, but changing the titles didn't fix that. I've reindexed my library. And they are working individually it is just when they are together.

Anybody have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Deleted one and recreated it. They now don't have consecutive IDs and they work. Still don't really know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little late reply, but in case someone else has the same problem and finds this thread:

Check that the check box "Remove Duplicate Results" in the Search Web Part is unchecked.

Another solution is to set the Trim Dublicates Properties to False in the web part code: http://thesharepointlife.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-not-display-all-results-2/comment-page-1/#comment-488

Comment: We tried that, but we ended up with duplicates in our list. So that was bad the other direction. It would be great if there was some explanation of what SP search considers a duplicate.

Comment: But I don't see how this setting could create duplicates, since it just controls the display of the search result. If you ended up with duplicates, they must have been there all the time but just not visible before.

Comment: Right, it wasn't creating duplicates, but then they showed. We are using cross-site publishing and occasionally there are some hiccups in our crawls. Not removing duplicates we get the occasional duplicate and removing SP removes the actual duplicates and some things that weren't actually duplicates.